# Adding a zero and decimal place to int

Tags: c#

I am looking for a relatively simple way to convert an integer value, which is guaranteed to be between 0 and 100, to it's decimal percentage equivalent. What I mean is if I were to have a number like 33, I would want to add a zero and a decimal place in front of it, so it would become 0.33(33%).

Here is what I have as a solution so far:

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
     int number = 33;
     Console.WriteLine(ConvertToPercent(number));
     Console.Read();
}

private static double ConvertToPercent(int value)
{
     if (value >= 100)
     {
         return 1.0D;
     }
     if (value <= 0)
     {
         return 0.0D;
     }
     return Double.Parse("0." + value);
}
```

Is there a better, more performant way to do this using existing .NET functionality?

**EDIT:**

My final solution to this problem in a single method:

```
public static double ConvertToPercent( int value )
{
     return ( double )( ( value < 0 ) ? 0 : ( value > 100 ) ? 100 : value ) / 100;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
decimal dec = (decimal)number / 100;
```

Comment: This works, but I still have to clamp the number between 0 and 100, which is not an issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Double.Parse` you can try just `(decimal)value * 0.01m`. The rest is fine.